# Syntax Error when converting .ui file to .py with Qt designer using pyuic5

Tags: spyder, pyqt5, qt-designer

So I've installed PyQt, and Qtdesigner and created my .ui file with a designed app (I'm just a beginner), but I keep getting a syntax error whenever I try to convert the file so I could use it in the python editor ( I work with Spyder from WinPython windows 32 bit)[This the code I try :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCPGE.png)

Comment: If you can't read the picture here's its content [In 5] :pushd"C:\Users\ghita\Desktop\Dev apps\Apps Python"
C:\Users\ghita\Desktop\Dev apps\Apps Python
Out[5]: ['C:\\']

pyuic5 -o design1.py design1.ui
  File "<ipython-input-6-808fd750dad4>", line 1
    pyuic5 -o design1.py design1.ui
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a windows commandline (like `cmd.exe`) to run `pyuic`, not a Python commandline.

I'm not sure if the Spyder shell allows you to do so (maybe it'll work with quotes, like with `pushd` above?), but it'll surely work in cmd.exe.